# Scrapy - Python - Scraping all text with p in a div

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I am trying to scrapy a text from this div

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h3 class="c-panel__section-heading">Reply</h3>
    <div class="textAreaContainer closed">

        <div contenteditable="true" class="customTextArea" id="Message" name="Message">
            <p>Dear Customer,&nbsp;</p>
            <p>the&nbsp;<span style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">MFDeviceMT.dll is a Matrox driver related dll, if you're not using a MATROX card on the server where you encountered the issue you can temporarily ignore it.</span></p>
            <p><span style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">We have however forwarder the problem to our developing team, thank you for the feedback.</span></p>
            <p><span style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">Best Regards.</span></p>
            -------------- -------------- ----------- Email send to: martin.bonato@brasvideo.com;b2w.shoptime@brasvideo.com Email send cc: supporto@etere.com
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But now the site implemented the tag

and I cant scrapy all the text
I m using this command

```
sel.xpath('//*[@id="Message"]/text()').extract()[-1]
```

and it returns

All the text in the last p tag

So how can I scrapy all text in the div with the p tag

Answer (score 0):

You want to scrape all text of `p`s seprately? loop through them

```
for p in sel.css('#Message p'):
   all_text = "".join(p.css("*::text").extract())
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way

```
sel.xpath('//*[@id="solutionsContainer"]/div[last()]/div[last()]/div//text()').extract()
for i_msg in ultima_msg:
            limpa_msg = limpa_msg + i_msg.strip()
```

Your way is simpler I think

But thanks all